# How could I divide a javascript class into several files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

For example, suppose that there's a file contains one class.

```
// a.js -> constructor, function1, function2
const AClass = class {
    constructor() {}
    function1() {}
    function2() {}
}
```

When function1 and function2 become too long, I want to separate them to another file.

```
// a.js -> constructor
// b.js -> function1
// c.js -> function2
```

Can I do this in JavaScript? I don't want to do as below.

```
// a.js
const fn1 = require("./b.js");
const AClass = class {
    constructor() {}
    function1() {fn1()}
}
```

Comment: "When function1 and function2 become too long"...why would you feel you need to do that? How would it help you? It just makes it less readable. I can't think of a good reason to want to do this really. Being "too long" is not a good reason IMO - if the code is long, it's long. So what? Compress it if you really want to, or find ways to make it less verbose, if you think it matters. I think this is a retrograde step in terms of code maintainability. It's also slightly less efficient for the machine to have to load an extra file in order to run the application.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for your suggestion, but I'm now writing server-side code, so I think there is no problem when I dividing a long code. (Some file I/O delay can be exist but I think it's not big.) Also, in my case, It's more understandable when code is divided into several names. This can be a bad habit when I'm working on a team project, but now I'm working on personal project. So thanks again, but, for now, I think this can make me more productive.

Comment: "code is divided into several names" ok but names != files, necessarily. If you have a good class and name structure, and an IDE where you can efficiently find code and trace things, then the physical location of the code is irrelevant really. Anyway that's my final point on the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [JS Prototype's chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). Basically having as many files as you wish and just use `extend` and have a mixins file with `function1` and `function2`, but this is really inefficient.

Additionally, you could just use the prototype chain and add the functions to it whenever you want, for example:

```
class A {
    say() {console.log("hey!")}
}

var foo = new A
foo.say() // hey!

A.prototype.yell = function(con) {console.info(con)}

foo.yell("hmmm...") // hmmm...
```

And you could do this in any file you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud `bind` the instance context to each function when it is initialized on `constructor`.

### Prototype Example

```js
function myFunc() {
  console.info(this.foo);
}

class AClass {
  constructor() {
    this.foo = 'Test';
    this.function1 = myFunc.bind(this);
  }
}
```

### Simple definition Example

```js
class PartialClass {
  constructor() {
    const methods = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this);
    methods.push(...Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.__proto__));

    methods
      // Remove duplicates
      .filter((item, pos) => methods.indexOf(item) === pos)
      // Get only functions
      .filter((p) => typeof this[p] === 'function')
      // Bind
      .forEach((fn) => {
        this[fn] = this[fn].bind(this);
      });
  }
}

function partialFunction1() {
  console.info('Foo', foo);
  alert(this.foo);
}

class AClass extends PartialClass {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.foo = 'Test context';
  }
  
  function1 = partialFunction1;
}

const x = new AClass();
x.function1();
```

## With TypeScript

`commons/PartialClass.ts`

```js
export abstract class PartialClass {
  constructor() {
    const methods = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this);
    // @ts-ignore
    methods.push(...Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.__proto__));

    methods
      // Remove duplicates
      .filter((item, pos) => methods.indexOf(item) === pos)
      // Get only functions
      // @ts-ignore
      .filter((p) => typeof this[p] === 'function')
      // Bind
      .forEach((fn) => {
        // @ts-ignore
        this[fn] = this[fn].bind(this);
      });
  }
}
```

`AClass/partials/function1.ts`

```js
import type { AClass } from '.'; // <-- Note: Use `import type`!

export default function function1(this: AClass, pararm1: string) {
  console.info('Foo', foo, pararm1);
  alert(this.foo, pararm1);
}
```

`AClass/index.ts`

```js
import { PartialClass } from '../commons/PartialClass';
import function1 from './partials/function1';

export class AClass extends PartialClass {
  foo = 'Test!';

  function1 = function1;
}
```

```js
import { AClass } from './AClass';
const x = new AClass();
x.function1('Param X');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written [an article about this](https://sgmonda.medium.com/dividing-nestjs-classes-in-smaller-files-2b18b200d030), taking special attention to TypeScript to ensure `this` works as expected from each file.

Basically, you'll see how to achieve this structure:

```js
- ...
- MyAwesomeClass/
  - index.ts
  - MyAwesomeClass.ts
  - methods/
    - index.ts
    - getName.ts
    - setName.ts
- ...
```